# Loading image into flash project dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to create an as3 project that dynamically pulls images from a database and sticks them into the framework of a flash movie that I making with this. Currently I am following a tutorial (in as2, and I am converting it to as3 as I go along) and am trying to get images to load from the same directory as the project, but I am having issues with the Loader. I am a complete newb at as3 and as such have almost no idea what I am doing, so I come to you guys for help as to why my program won't work properly. Here is the entire code from my project.

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.*;
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

var xmlPath = "content.xml";
var photos_xml:XML = new XML();
var imageList:XMLList = new XMLList();
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML)
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imageLoader.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initHandler);
imageLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
var currentImage:Number = 0;
var timer:Number;

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlPath));

//stop();

function loadXML(e:Event):void
{
    photos_xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    imageList = photos_xml.image.text();

    //for (var i:int = 0; i < imageList.length(); i++)
//  {
//      trace (imageList[i]);
//  }

    loadImage();
}

function loadImage()
{
    var loadURL = imageList[currentImage]
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(loadURL);
    var targetClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    targetClip.alpha = 0;
    clearInterval(timer);

    //trace(loadURL);
    //======== imageLoader refuses to throw events! ===========
    trace(req.url)
    imageLoader.load(req);
    targetClip.addChild(imageLoader);
    shell_mc.pics_mc.addChild(targetClip);

    trace("I am in loadImage");
}

function setTimer():void
{
    timer = setInterval(loadImage, 1000);
}

function removePrevious(prevImg:MovieClip):void
{
    if (prevImg != null)
    {
        removeChild(prevImg);
        //removeMovieClip(prevImg);
    }

    //trace(currentImage);
    currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % imageList.length();
}

function initHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace("I am in initHandler");
    TweenLite.to(shell_mc.background_mc, 0.25, {width:event.target.width + 20, height:event.target.height + 20, ease:Quad.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(shell_mc.border_mc, 0.25, {width:event.target.width, height:event.target.height, ease:Quad.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(shell_mc.mask_mc, 0.25, {width:event.target.width, height:event.target.height, ease:Quad.easeOut});

    var clipXTarg = Math.round((stage.width / 2) - ((event.target.width + 20) / 2));
    var clipYTarg = Math.round((stage.height / 2) - ((event.target.height + 20) / 2));
    TweenLite.to(shell_mc, 0.25, {x:clipXTarg, y:clipYTarg, ease:Quad.easeOut});

    var prevImgNum:Number;
    if (currentImage == 0)
    {
        prevImgNum = imageList.length() - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        prevImgNum = currentImage - 1;
    }
    var prevImg = shell_mc.pics_mc["pic" + prevImgNum];
    TweenLite.to(prevImg, 0.25, {autoAlpha:0, onComplete:removePrevious(prevImg)});
}

function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace("I am in completeHandler");
    TweenLite.to(event.target, 0.25, {autoAlpha:100, delay:0.25});
    setTimer();
}
```

The issue here is that the imageLoader won't throw any events as it is loading the image file, and there are absolutely no errors to give me any clue why it might be failing. Here is how my xml file looks:

Assets/DaVinci1.jpg
Assets/DaVinci2.jpg
Assets/DaVinci3.jpg

Both the project and the Assets folder are in the same directory, so the filepath should not be an issue, but otherwise I don't know. Here is the tutorial I am following (http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/xml/flash-slideshow-xml/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are loading the `swf` or `image` types you need to add eventListener not to the `loader` but to the `contentLoaderInfo`

```
contentLoader   = new Loader ();

contentLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete );
contentLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener ( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, handleProgress );
contentLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener ( ErrorEvent.ERROR, handleError );
contentLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener ( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError );
contentLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener ( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleError );
```

and whe you need to load data ( text based files ) you doing like with your XMLLoader

```
dataLoader              = new URLLoader ();

dataLoader.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete );
dataLoader.addEventListener ( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, handleProgress );         
dataLoader.addEventListener ( ErrorEvent.ERROR, handleError );
dataLoader.addEventListener ( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError );
dataLoader.addEventListener ( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleError );
```

Comment: You're a genius! I got the code to go to the next part thanks to you :D! I'm surprised no place I checked actually pointed out the fact that the eventlisteners should go on contentLoaderInfo. Seems like a good bit of info to know. But thanks again, now to get the images loading :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your listeners onto `loader.contentLoaderInfo`, not `loader`.

```
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initHandler);
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace("I am in completeHandler");
    TweenLite.to(event.target.content, 0.25, {autoAlpha:100, delay:0.25});
    setTimer();
}
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#contentLoaderInfo

Comment: It doesn't look like you added the target.content to the stage or other previously added element. Therefore I don't think it will show up.

Comment: He adds it in the loadImage() function `targetClip.addChild(imageLoader);
`

Comment: You can do it both ways, add a `Loader` directly to display list, or you can wait until it loads and then add the loaded content to display list. I prefer the second option, because then i can get rid of the `Loader` and all listeners to prevent memory leaks...